# SQL Server import from Access

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I am trying to copy Access (2013) database tables to SQL Server 2014. Access Database Engine Reports conflict between 64 bit SQL and 32 bit Access. Table > Tasks > Import gives attached Report.  There are no relationships and No Indexes.
Can any one help ??

Operation stopped...

- Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)
- Initializing Connections (Success)
- Setting SQL Command (Success)
- Setting Source Connection (Success)
- Setting Destination Connection (Success)
- Validating (Success)
  Messages

  - Warning 0x80049304: Data Flow Task 1: Warning: Could not open global shared memory to communicate with performance DLL; data flow performance counters are not available.  To resolve, run this package as an administrator, or on the system's console.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Prepare for Execute (Success)
- Pre-execute (Success)
- Executing (Success)
- Copying to `Actions` (Error)
  Messages

  - Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E2F.
    An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E2F  Description: "The changes you requested to the table were not successful because they would create duplicate values in the index, primary key, or relationship.  Change the data in the field or fields that contain duplicate data, remove the index, or redefine the index to permit duplicate entries and try again.".
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
  - Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Destination - Actions.Inputs[Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC020907B occurred, and the error row disposition on "Destination - Actions.Inputs[Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
  - Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - Actions" (121) failed with error code 0xC0209029 while processing input "Destination Input" (134). The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
- Post-execute (Success)
  Messages

  - Information 0x4004300b: Data Flow Task 1: "Destination - Actions" wrote 0 rows.
    (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Answer (score 0):

It is too clear that there are duplicated rows or null value in MS access.
For the second error, you may need to visit this link or information
https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/573638/ssis-package-failes-with-ole-db-error-when-using-transaction-support-on-sequence-container

The third one results from you may fail the whole package transformation when you encounter an error

Comment: yes, it's worth trying to copy the tables from Access 2013 to Access 2013 first (strange, I know) and seeing what happens. it might uncover problems you weren't aware of.